# SP online : administrator or not?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

I am sharepoint administrator on this site and i cant fully use "document library settings" like i cant save document library as a template or even edit permissions

[image]

I expected that i would see someting like this

[image]

Is there any way to get rights to do that? Or wheres the problem?

Comment: Do you have 'Full Control'?  Can you check your user name in the settings to see if you have the Full Control permission?  You might only have something like Design or Edit...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are trying to change the settings of a modern teamsite. If that's true, Microsoft has removed a lot of settings for those sites. Probably to prevent unwanted changes that might conflict with updates they might do in the future.

Comment: Where can i found what kind of team site do i use? And is there any chance how to change those things in a modern team site?

Comment: If it's a modern team site, the permissions are handled through an Office 365 Group. This might be a good starting point: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2

The general recommendation seems to be, to make as little changes to the default as possible. Microsoft did switch those feature off with a reason (which we might not know)

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue happen on other libraries? Or other lists? Create a new library and check the results.

Does this issue occur with other site collection admins? Please add a new user and then set the user as site collection admin to see what happens.

I guess you are working on a Office 365 Group Site, which has several differences from the type of SharePoint site. You can try to install SharePoint Online Management Shell, PowerShell, and follow this post to enable the custom scripts for SharePoint Online Group Sites.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_shareon/save-list-as-a-template-on-office-365-groups/886b5f92-6fab-450f-8b60-d97cc493324d?auth=1

After doing above steps, go to library settings and check the results.

Note: There are different kinds of admin roles in SharePoint Online, for more information about SharePoint Online admin role, you can read this article.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-sharepoint-admin-role-in-office-365-f08144d5-9d50-4922-8e77-4e1a27b40705?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US